# Javascript - Getting data from XML for later use... put in array or object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am extracting a bunch of data from an XML file using jQuery. I need to use the data to fill in image paths, names, etc.

What is the best way to gather all of this data for use? For instance, I get everything like so:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "stuff.xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function(xml) {
                        $(xml).find('speaker').each(function(){
                            var img_path = $(this).find('speaker_image').text();
                            var name_text = $(this).find('speaker_name').text();
                            // should I build an array or object here?
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```

Should I stick everything into an array in the success method? Maybe in an object? What I will do is take the collected data and use it to build a list of names and images. There will be quite a few elements in this and it will look something like (with `img_path` being used in the image url and `name_text` being used for the label:

```
<ul>
<li><img src="images/bobsmith.jpg" /><br /><lable>Bob S. Smith</label></li>
<li><img src="images/crystalforehead.jpg" /><br /><lable>Crystal X. Forehead</label></li>
...
</ul>
```

What is the best way to handle the collected data so I can go through and build the html I need using it?

Comment: Just an FYI, in Javascript, arrays ARE objects and you can have an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it into an array object if you need to re-use:

```
function linkItem(linkImage, linkText)
{
    this.linkImage = linkImage;
    this.linkText = linkText;
};

function mylist()
    this.speakerList = new Array();
    $(xml).find('speaker').each(function()
    {
        this.speakerList [$(this).index()] = new linkItem($(this).find('speaker_image').text(), $(this).find('speaker_name').text());
    };
};
```

Just build it if you use only once:

```
var myhtml = ""
$(xml).find('speaker').each(function(){ 
    myhtml = myhtml + '<li><img src="' + $(this).find('speaker_image').text() + '" /><br /><label>' + $(this).find('speaker_name').text() + '</label></li>'; 
});
```

then use it:

```
$(selector).append(myhtml);
```

or

```
$(selector).innerHtml(myhtml);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need to re-use the data from the XML file, why not build the DOM elements whilst you are reading it?

So for example in your success method:

```
$(xml).find('speaker').each(function(){
    var img_path = $(this).find('speaker_image').text();
    var name_text = $(this).find('speaker_name').text();
    var html = '<li><img src="' + img_path + '" /><br /><label>' + name_text + '</label></li>';
    $("#myList").append(html);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This will put the retrieved results in an array using `push`:

```
   success: function(xml) {
            var results = [];
            $(xml).find('speaker').each(function(){
                results.push($(this));
            });
```